# Evaluating XPath expressions in Wiremock

Tags: java, xml, wiremock

I am using Wiremock for testing and I am facing the below issue.

There are 2 scenarios

1. When the request would be coming as below

```
<Body>
    <ElementA>Element A</ElementA>
    <ElementB>123<ElementB>
</Body>
```

Here we only need to check that the value for element B should be 123.

2. When the request would be coming as below

```
<Body>
    <ElementA flag="true">Element A</ElementA>
    <ElementB>123<ElementB>
</Body>
```

Here we need to check that the value for element B should be 123 and the value for flag should be true as well.

Now I want my wiremock to return different responses in both the cases and my wiremock config files looks something like this.

1. For case 1

```
{
  "request": {
    "url": "/",
    "method": "POST",
    "bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "matchesXPath": {
          "expression": "//ElementB/text()",
          "contains": "123"
        }

      },{
      "absent": {
        "expression":  "//ElementA[@flag=true]"
      }
      }
    ]
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "someFile.xml",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    }
  }
}
```

But here it only takes absent as true and the other element does not comes.
Example from wiremock :

```
  "bodyPatterns" : [ {
        "matchesXPath" : {
          "expression" : "//ElementA/text()",
          "contains" : "123"
        }
      }, {
        "absent" : true
      } ]
```

2. For case 2

```
{
  "request": {
    "url": "/",
    "method": "POST",
    "bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "matchesXPath": {
          "expression": "//ElementB[text()='123']"

        },
        "matchesXPath": {
          "expression": "//ElementA[@flag]",
          "contains": "true"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "someotherFile.xml",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    }
  }
}
```

But somehow it is not able to return the response in case 1 and in case 2 it does not care for the first condition it only checks if the value for flag is true.

Any help/ pointers on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced that you need the `absent` flag. I think you can use priorities instead to force WireMock to check the more specific request before moving to the more general response.

I also think that there is an error in how you're checking the XPath in Case 2. I'd try something like...

```
{
  "priority": 1,
  "request": {
    "url": "/",
    "method": "POST",
    "bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "matchesXPath": {
          "expression": "//ElementB[text()]",
          "contains": "123"
        },
        "matchesXPath": {
          "expression": "//ElementA[@flag]",
          "contains": "true"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "someFile.xml",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    }
  }
}
```

Look at the addition of `"priority": 1`. I also think you could change the `matchesXPath` objects to simply check for the values if you don't need them to match a regex pattern.
`"matchesXPath": "//ElementB[text() = 123]"`

```
{
  "priority": 2,
  "request": {
    "url": "/",
    "method": "POST",
    "bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "matchesXPath": {
          "expression": "//ElementB[text()]",
          "contains": "123"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "someotherFile.xml",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    }
  }
}
```

Because the priority 1 mapping checks for `flag=true`, it is the case that a match on the priority 2 mapping does not contain Element A with a flag=true attribute. So, after WireMock checks the priority 1 mapping (which requires a match on `flag=true`), it checks the priority 2 mapping (which only requires that ElementB's text = 123).